# VB.NET-MYSQL - filtrar grilla mediante combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hola buenas noches a todos, otra vez consultando a ver si me pueden ayudar un pokito...tengo que filtrar un datagridview segun lo que seleccione en un combobox...hasta el momento lo que hago es pasar el id del item del combobox a un textbox, i ese valor (un entero) pasarlo como parametro en la qery del filtro...tengo esta funcion:

```vb
Public Sub filtrarNivel()
conexionMYSQL = New MySqlConnection

conexionMYSQL.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;User Id=soporte;database=db_incidencias_muniquel;password=123")

Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter

Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim fuente As New BindingSource

'Usamos un Capturador de Errores
Try
conexionMYSQL.Open()

'Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_incidencias"

'Dim query As String = ("SELECT inc.id_incidencia, inc.fecha_registro, ingr.identificacion_metodo AS metodo, est.identificacion_estado AS estado, tip.identificacion_solicitud AS tipoSolicitud, niv.identificacion_nivel AS nivel, fun.nombre_funcionario as nombreSoporte, inc.detalle_incidencia FROM tbl_incidencias inc LEFT JOIN tbl_niveles_incidencia niv ON inc.id_nivel=niv.id_nivel LEFT JOIN tbl_tipo_solicitud tip ON inc.id_tipo_solicitud=tip.id_tipo_solicitud LEFT JOIN tbl_funcionario_soporte fun ON inc.id_registro_soporte=fun.id_registro_soporte LEFT JOIN tbl_estados_incidencia est ON inc.id_estado=est.id_estado LEFT JOIN tbl_metodos_ingreso_incidencia ingr ON inc.id_metodo_ingreso=ingr.id_metodo_ingreso WHERE inc.id_registro= @id_registro ")

Dim query As String = ("SELECT inc.id_incidencia, inc.fecha_registro, ingr.identificacion_metodo AS metodo, est.identificacion_estado AS estado, tip.identificacion_solicitud AS tipoSolicitud, niv.identificacion_nivel AS nivel, fun.nombre_funcionario as nombreSoporte, inc.detalle_incidencia FROM tbl_incidencias inc LEFT JOIN tbl_niveles_incidencia niv ON inc.id_nivel=niv.id_nivel LEFT JOIN tbl_tipo_solicitud tip ON inc.id_tipo_solicitud=tip.id_tipo_solicitud LEFT JOIN tbl_funcionario_soporte fun ON inc.id_registro_soporte=fun.id_registro_soporte LEFT JOIN tbl_estados_incidencia est ON inc.id_estado=est.id_estado LEFT JOIN tbl_metodos_ingreso_incidencia ingr ON inc.id_metodo_ingreso=ingr.id_metodo_ingreso WHERE inc.id_nivel=@id_nivel AND inc.id_registro='1'")

comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_nivel", txtIdNivel.Text)

comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)

da.SelectCommand = comando

da.Fill(dt)

fuente.DataSource = dt

dgIncidenciasAsignadas.DataSource = fuente

da.Update(dt)

conexionMYSQL.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
End Try
```

pero me da un error de coneversion select ...en integer y ahi me quedo...agradezco desde ya si alguien ha tenido un drama similar que me pudiera orientar

Comment: Deberías especificar exactamente cual es la excepción que te da. Pero, por decirte algo, el párametro de la consulta lo pasas como string cuando intuyo que es un int. Intenta esta linea: `comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_nivel", Convert.ToIn32(txtIdNivel.Text))`

Comment: hola estimado gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda...probando con la conversion me arroja el error: "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Comment: Claro. Eso es porque tienes la definicion `comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)` despues de intentar acceder a los parametros. Debes ponerla antes

Comment: Te agregué una respuesta por si mis comentarios no habían quedado claros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores en tu código. Por un lado, el parámetro de tu consulta lo estás pasando como `string`, cuando por su nombre imagino que es un `int`.

Por el otro, estas tratando de acceder a la colección `Parameters` de tu comando antes de definir el comando.

Con todo esto, estas dos lineas de tu código deberían ser así:

```
comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_nivel", Convert.ToIn32(txtIdNivel.Text))
```

Comment: gracias estimado, ahora si funciona....muchas gracias